# Delphi 10.4 ClientDataSet + SQL Server executes stored procedure with unrecognizable spaces after parameters

Tags: android, sql-server, delphi, delphi-10.4-sydney

I am using delphi 10.4 to develop android program, to connect to database I am using TSQLConnection(datasnap) and TCLientDataSet. the statement is

```
var orderNo,date:string;

orderNo := '';
date := '2024-02-04 00:00:00';

With QSysDataSet do
begin
    close; 
    commandText:= 'exec S_SignSR :orderNo,:Date';

    Params.ParamByName('orderNo').dataType := ftstring;
    Params.ParamByName('orderNo').ParamType := ptInputOutput;
    Params.ParamByName('orderNo').size := 20;
    Params.ParamByName('orderNo').value := orderNo;

    Params.ParamByName('Date').dataType := ftstring;
    Params.ParamByName('Date').ParamType := ptInputOutput;
    Params.ParamByName('Date').size := 30;
    Params.ParamByName('Date').value := date;

    execute;
end.
```

sql server procedure statement is

```
create procedure S_SignSR
    @orderNo varchar(20) output
    @date varchar(30) output
as
begin
    update table1 set ddate = @date 
end
```

But after execution the statement traced in sqlserver is

```
declare @p6 varchar(21)
set @p6='                     ' -- There are 21 spaces here
declare @p9 varchar(31)
set @p9='2024-02-04 00:00:00            ' -- There is spaces after this, with a total length of 31
exec sp_executesql N'exec S_SignSR @p1，@p2',N'@p1 varchar(21) output,@p2 varchar(31) output',@p6 output,@p9 output
```

Execute `update table1 set ddate = @date` in database will report "Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from string";

I try `insert into temp(text1) values (''''+@date+'111');select * from temp;`the only data in the table is `'2024-02-04 00:00:00`

using `set @date = rtrim(@date)` it not works, but using `set @date = substring(@date,1,19)` it works.

If I skipped setting the param size

```
//Params.ParamByName('orderNo').size := 20;
//Params.ParamByName('Date').size := 30;
```

the statement traced is

```
declare @p6 varchar(2)
set @p6='  ' -- There are 2 spaces here
declare @p9 varchar(21)
set @p9='2024-02-04 00:00:00  ' -- There is spaces after this, with a total length of 21
```

If I used

```
    Params.ParamByName('orderNo').size := 20;
    Params.ParamByName('orderNo').AsString := orderNo;
    Params.ParamByName('Date').size := 30;
    Params.ParamByName('Date').AsString := date;
```

the statement traced is

```
declare @p6 nvarchar(21)
set @p6=N'          븀࿄봈࿄࿄률࿄�࿄'--This will display garbled characters
declare @p7 int
set @p7=3
declare @p9 nvarchar(31)
set @p9=N'2024-02-24 00:00:00           '
```

If I used

```
    //Params.ParamByName('orderNo').size := 20;
    Params.ParamByName('orderNo').AsString := orderNo;
    //Params.ParamByName('Date').size := 30;
    Params.ParamByName('Date').AsString := date;
```

the statement traced is

```
declare @p6 nvarchar(1)
set @p6=N' '
declare @p7 int
set @p7=3
declare @p9 nvarchar(1)
set @p9=N'2'
```

I tried to change data types like widestring(date)/ansistring(date)/utf8encode(date),They all don't work

I suspect that the trailing spaces are garbled code that can't be displayed, probably due to encoding conversions.

The date format is not the point, as I have been using string type transfer throughout the process. For example, `orderNo` also has the same problem. The key is to solve the problem of unknown spaces after parameters are passed into the database

How should this problem be solved

Comment: What's is datatype `ftstring`?

Comment: Have you tried to skip setting the param size?

Comment: Yeah it looks like setting the size is making it a fixed length string and padding with spaces

Comment: Sending dates and times to the database in string format is almost certainly a bad thing (why aren't you using `ftDateTime`?), but if you must do that against SQL Server try using yyyy-mm-ddTHH:MM:SS format so as to avoid conversion errors that can happen when `SET DATEFORMAT` isn't as you expect on your SQL Server instance. i.e.: `2024-02-04T00:00:00`

Comment: @DelphiCoder If I skip setting the param size,the sql statement is `set @p6='  ';set @p9='2024-002-04 00:00:00  '`,There will still be two spaces in the end and report error

Comment: @AlwaysLearning date format is not the point,because aflter `set @date = substring(@date,1,19)` it works,and `orderNo` also has the same problem.

Comment: Well, so far as the date parameter is concerned the trailing spaces don't matter. When you start getting date format conversion errors this will be why. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/jVhKm-9G)

Comment: @AlwaysLearning So I think this may seem like a space, but in reality it's not a space, but rather a character that cannot be displayed under the current encoding.For example,`insert into temp(text1) values (''''+@date+'111');select * from temp;`The following `111` will not be inserted into the table

Comment: Can you reproduce it in a Windows FMX app?

Comment: Please provide your table schema, and an actual [mre] that demonstrates the issue. Small snippets of code that are out of context and based on some unknown table columns is just asking us to speculate about possible causes.

Answer (score 2):

Finally I add a TADOConnection and a TADOStoredProc in server builded by vcl

and used following code in fmx client to call server's method

```
try
    SQLServerMethod := TSQLServerMethod.Create(nil);
    SQLServerMethod.SQLConnection := SQLConnection1;
    SQLServerMethod.ServerMethodName := 'THHSVMethods.s_sign';
    SQLServerMethod.params[0].value := orderNo;
    SQLServerMethod.params[1].value := date;
    SQLServerMethod.ExecuteMethod;
    orderNo := SQLServerMethod.params[0].value;
    date := SQLServerMethod.params[1].value;
finnaly
    SQLServerMethod.close;
    FreeAndNil(SQLServerMethod);
end;
```

the statement traced in sqlserver is No more spaces

It may be a bit strange to use both TSQLConnection and TADOConnection in the server at the same time, but I haven't found a better way